# Calculation with a past datetime considering DST timezone in bash

Tags: bash, date, datetime, dst, timedelta

I am trying to mock a calculation with the last datetime in which Brazil had the daylight savings change end (`2019-02-16`).

For testing sake, I am adding one minute to `23:59:00`, and check if the computation reckons one hour subtraction, therefore yielding `23:00:00` on the same date.

I am running bash on Mac os Catalina:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, versão 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0)

$ date --debug -d "$(date '+2019-02-16 23:59:00-02') + 1min"
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2019-02-16
date: parsed time part: 23:59:00 UTC-02
date: parsed relative part: +1 minutes
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (-02) ### Correct, but fixed timezone on timestamp
date: using specified time as starting value: '23:59:00'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2019-02-16 23:59:00 TZ=-02'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2019-02-16 23:59:00 TZ=-02' = 1550368740 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+0 hours, +1 minutes, +0 seconds, +0 ns),
date:     new time = 1550368800 epoch-seconds
date: warning: daylight saving time changed after time adjustment ### Nice!
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1550368800.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-02-17 02:00:00 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-02-16 23:00:00 (UTC-03)
Sáb Fev 16 23:00:00 -03 2019 ### Correct output
```

However, I would like to specify on the timestamp some value that it's not the hardcoded timezone value at that time.

I've tried to put `%Z` on the inner `date` command, but the timezone information is wrong: (`-03` instead of DST `-02`):

```
$ date --debug -d "$(date '+2019-02-16 23:59:00-%Z') + 1min"
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2019-02-16
date: parsed time part: 23:59:00 UTC-03
date: parsed relative part: +1 minutes
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (-03)
date: using specified time as starting value: '23:59:00'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2019-02-16 23:59:00 TZ=-03'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2019-02-16 23:59:00 TZ=-03' = 1550372340 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+0 hours, +1 minutes, +0 seconds, +0 ns),
date:     new time = 1550372400 epoch-seconds
date: warning: daylight saving time changed after time adjustment ### Should be good....
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1550372400.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-02-17 03:00:00 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-02-17 00:00:00 (UTC-03)
Dom Fev 17 00:00:00 -03 2019 ### ...Wrong
```

How could I specify the DST timezone at that date ?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: it's a bit confusing to me which TZ you want to specify. `date +%Z` just output current TZ.

Comment: Hi @pynexj. Your comment sparkled an idea which solved the problem: I only need to know the correct tz to current date (i.e. final command will have `+%Y-%m-%d`). So I changed my computer clock to 16/02/2019 and indeed my second command works correctly too in this setup. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: (I mean obviously when the current date falls on `-02` DST).